# Combining CSS properties

Tags: css, xhtml, refactoring

I am trying to combine some of my CSS and it is kind of an easy questions but I am kind of having some trouble, i have this code:

```
h2.post-title, h2.post-title a{
    display:block;
    background-color:#000;
    padding:3px;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font:lighter 130% Georgia, Arial;
}
```

Do I need to have both of those selectors there? The only time I will be using the `h2.post-title` it will be a link. Any suggestions, I tried removing the first one, but it made it HUGE.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the h2 font styling, it will revert to its default font size which is pretty big. You could set it up separately:

```
h2.post-title {
    font-size:130%;
}
```

But it will take up more space than simply setting both selectors to the same style. My advice — leave it as it is unless you have a good reason to change it.

Comment: Thank you, i just wasnt sure if there was a more proper way to do so.

Comment: This is a bad idea. The CSS won't do what it appears to do at first sight. Both the *lighter* `font-weight` and *130%* `font-size` are relative values, so the font size you end up with won't be 130%, but 130% * 130% = 169%. The font-weight probably won't be affected, because most fonts only have two weights anyway. Also, the paddings of the `h2` and `a` will add up to `6px`.

Answer (score -1):

The thing is that "h2.post-title a" only applyes to the <a>-element of your code. The browser uses standard css on the <h2>-tag!

Lets have a look on your HTML:

```
<h2 class="post-title"><a href="#">Clickable title</a></h2>
```

You need rules to both the <h2> and the <a>-tag. To do that, you need do include both *h2* and *a* in the stylesheet (as you described).

A solution might be to remove the default styling of <h2>, by some of the many [reset css](http://www.google.no/search?client=opera&rls=nb&q=reset+css&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)-rules you'll find on the Internet.

An other solution would be to move the class-spesification from "h2" over to "a" (and style just the "a.post-title" attribute in CSS):

```
<h2><a class="post-title" href="#">Clickable title</a></h2>
```

Or maybe you can remove the <h2>-tag completely, just print out <a>. But this might break your semantic.